# Unable to see any /sys/devices/xx interface created from kernel module loaded through k_vendor_module.rc

Tags: android-source, device-driver, android-kernel

Trying to integrate a third part kernel vendor module to our android stack. Since this is module is not needed as part of early-init, decided to not put it under BOARD_VENDOR_RAMDISK_KERNEL_MODULES_LOAD which worked in the first place.

Now I'm creating a .rc file to load them.

.rc file looks like this:

```
on boot
    start xx_module_insmod_sh

service xx_module_insmod_sh /vendor/etc/xx_modules_run.sh sys.all.boot.ready
    class main
    user root
    group root system
    disabled
    oneshot
```

xx_modules_run.sh

```
#!/system/bin/sh
insmod /vendor/lib/modules/xyz.ko
setprop $1 1
```

When I run them in the target, lsmod lists the node xyz.ko but the /sys/devices/virtual/inxx is not getting created. I can see the .rc and .sh file in the target in the /vendor/etc/init/* path.

But if I manually insmod it from the adb shell, I can see the /sys/devices/virtual/inxx.

Hard to debug this as there are no dmesg logs available from the bootup. Any help is appreciated.